# Make bash tab completion favor files/directories instead of $PATH

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm standing in a directory that looks like so:

```
$ ls
build  src  utils
```

Then writing this

```
$ ut
```

And pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>, makes bash autocomplete this:

```
$ utmpdump
```

What I wanted is to have `ut<tab>` complete the `utils/` directory that's in my current working directory, similar to e.g. writing `$ uti`<kbd>tab</kbd> so it completes as:

$ utils/

So it seems bash tries to autocomplete stuff in $PATH, can I make it favor the current directory in such a case ? (Without having to write the `./`)

Comment: After upgrading to stretch I now have this problem with `ve`TAB -- in Jessie it used to autocomplete `venv/` (what I'm hoping for, my default name for a python virtualenv), and now it is autocompleting `verify-uselistorder`.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your bashrc

```
shopt -s autocd
```

This will automatically `cd` into the path you wrote, if you only wrote the path.

And put `.` into you `$PATH`. In addition to what is already there such that it works for executing files, if the execution rights are given.

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: I'm not interrested in cd'ing into the directory, but tab-completing it as described in the question. Putting . in the path doesn't seem to help (unless the command I'm completing is in the current working directory)

Comment: @nos: You have not tested `shopt -s autocd` with [tab] key.

Comment: @Cyrus Sure I did. The very same thing happens in the 1. case, `ut<tab>` autocompletes to utmpdump. (The other case of  `uti<tab>` autocompletes as before to utils/ with the additional effect of pressing enter after utils/ cd's into that directory.)

Comment: @nos: okay, then I misunderstood you.